# New component that uses autocomplete

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm trying to create a new component that pretty much works as a pre-configured autocomplete.
The XBL components documentation is very brief, so I adapted as I could and reached this result:

```
<xbl:xbl xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
     xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:example="http://example.ro/xbl">

<xbl:binding
    id="example-judet"
    element="example|judet"
    xxbl:mode="lhha binding value">
    <metadata xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
        <display-name lang="ro">Judeţ</display-name>
        <icon lang="ro">
            <small-icon>/forms/orbeon/builder/images/listbox.png</small-icon>
            <large-icon>/forms/orbeon/builder/images/listbox.png</large-icon>
        </icon>
        <templates>
            <bind required="true()"/>
            <view>
                <fr:autocomplete
                    ref="xxf:binding('example-judet')"
                    labelref="@label"
                    resource="http://localhost/counties?search={$fr-search-value}">
                    <xf:label>Judeţ</xf:label>
                    <xf:hint/>
                    <xf:help/>
                    <xf:alert>Câmp obligatoriu</xf:alert>
                    <xf:itemset ref="item">
                        <xf:label ref="label"/>
                        <xf:value ref="value"/>
                    </xf:itemset>
                </fr:autocomplete>
            </view>
        </templates>
    </metadata>
</xbl:binding>
```

There are 2 problems:

1. The selector is not working anymore - it's not querying the service on value changes
2. The alert and help texts work, but they do not show up in the builder's "Control settings" dialog in the appropriate tabs

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have to check but I believe that the view template name must match the name of the component. If you want to use an `fr:autocomplete` within another XBL component, you can do that, but you cannot just put that component within the `templates/view` section of the XBL component's Form Builder metadata. In other words, try to follow instead the method used by [`fr:dropdown-select1`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/form-runner/jvm/src/main/resources/xbl/orbeon/dropdown-select1/dropdown-select1.xbl).

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason absolutely nothing gets displayed, both in form builder and in form runner..

Comment: Update: it was a typo, that's why nothing was showing.
Now it shows the input/dropdown, but it's the same issue: the selector is not getting the list on value change.
It's like the event is not triggered or something.